# Vloop using 2 values to search in Excel

Tags: excel, formula, indexof

I want to search the presence of either the presence of id_re or id. If i found at least one these two variables in my file1, i want to return the value of company in file2.
My formula:   =RECHERCHEV(C2&D2;'[File1.xlsx]Feuil1'!$A$2:$F$5;6;FAUX) 
The picture below explain more what i want. 
[image: Picture]

Thank you

Comment: You may like to look at the addressing syntax here: https://exceljet.net/formula/vlookup-from-another-workbook. Observe the placement of apostrophes.

Comment: Thank you but I did it and it doesn't work .. I just forget to added in the caption

Comment: Please post your formula in a legible manner, preferably as part of your question.

Comment: =RECHERCHEV(C2&D2;'[File1.xlsx]Feuil1'!$A$2:$F$5;6;FAUX)

Answer (score 0):

Your formula searches for C2&D2. If C2 = 11 and D2 = 12 then C2&D2 = "1112". I presume that one of the two cells is blank, however, so that your lookup value is either "11" or "12", a string in either case because of the concatenation. Not sure that it would find a number if the lookup range contains numbers. Your worksheet looks like it has numbers in column A.

If your intention is to look up either C2 or D2 you would require two separate lookups. You might construct something like this formula.

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(=RECHERCHEV(C2;'[File1.xlsx]Feuil1'!$A$2:$F$5;6;FAUX) , =RECHERCHEV(D2;'[File1.xlsx]Feuil1'!$A$2:$F$5;6;FAUX)),"Neither was found")
```

Comment: thank you .. where can i create VLOOKUP(1) and how to return may value of the company please??

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question but I have amended my answer to better show what I mean.

Comment: You'll probably want to replace IFERROR by the french equivalent; also keep in mind the order of the lookup might be important if the first line to match id_re isn't the same as the first to match id.
Try `=SIERREUR(RECHERCHEV(C2;Feuil1!$A$2:$F$5;6;FAUX);RECHERCHEV(D2;Feuil1!$B$2:$F$5;5;FAUX))` - looks up for the first company macthing id_re; if that fails, looks up for the first matching id - I omitted Variatus last IFERROR, so if there is no match for either, you'll get #N/A

Comment: The sequence of building the formula is to first make one VLOOKUP work, then the other one. Only when each one works can they be combined. So, which of the two VLOOKUPs doesn't work and why? I have pointed to the difference between numbers and strings. What is the format in C2? What is the format in A2:F5?